# For react native, is there a way to only reactive certain data from a json file and render it?

Tags: wordpress, react-native, filtering, display, data-processing

My JSON file structure is as follows :

```json
{
     "shopData": [
      {
         "shop_id" : "1",
         "shop_name":"NTUC",
         "itemData":[
             {
             "id" : "3",
             "shop_name":"NTUC",
             "image" :"https://i2.wp.com/www.downshiftology.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Baked-Salmon-1-2.jpg",
             "name":"Salmon fillet",
             "price": 16,
             "purchase_limit": "5",
             "stock": "20"
         },
         {
             "id" : "1",
             "shop_name" :"NTUC",
             "image" : "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1603664454146-50b9bb1e7afa?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fG9yYW5nZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80",
             "name" : "Orange",
             "price": 10,
             "purchase_limit": "3",
             "stock": "15"
          },
          {
             "id" : "2",
             "shop_name" :"NTUC",
             "image" :"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tomato_je.jpg",
             "name":"Tomato",
             "price": 5,
             "purchase_limit": "7",
             "stock": "18"
          } ,
         {
             "id" : "4",
             "shop_name" : "NTUC",
             "image": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRIK0wJschQcumCEBOnWbs6qcjZHcPpHPRETQ&usqp=CAU",
             "name":"Greens",
             "price": 3,
             "purchase_limit": "3",
             "stock": "25"
         }
 
 
         ]
         
       },
       {
         "shop_id" : "2",
         "shop_name":"GIANT",
         "itemData": [
             {
                 "id" : "5",
                 "shop_name" : "GIANT",
                 "image": "https://www.jocooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/dark-rye-bread-1-17.jpg",
                 "name" : "RyeBread",
                 "price": 20,
                 "purchase_limit": "5",
                 "stock": "15"
              },
              {
                "id" : "6",
                "shop_name" : "GIANT",
                "image": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQFca-tLIQoXKEBi8EkM4eAmh0cWccPtE34fA&usqp=CAU",
                "name" : "Carrot",
                "price": 7,
                "purchase_limit": "6",
                "stock": "15"
             }
 
         ]
 
 
       }
            
     ]   
}
```

For this, is there a way where i can selective choose which only one set of data to render on my Flatlist?

Like for example i only want to display the data with `shop_name = "GIANT"`

Edit: Is there any way to pick a specific item (shop) from the `shopData` array and then render them with the help of `FlatList` ?

Answer (score 0):

In React Native (and Javascript), you have to map through JSON data that are parsed as Javascript objects. And while looping through them (.e.g .map()), you can conditionally display them.

In a flatlist example however, you can prepare the data beforehand using useMemo to memorize your filtered data.

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'

const Component = (data) => {

    const finalDataToDisplay = useMemo(() => {
        return data.filter( x => x.shop_name === "GIANT")
    },[data])

    return       <FlatList
                        data={finalDataToDisplay}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                  />
}
```

We can then comfortably use `finalDataToDisplay` in flat list as the data source.

`.filter()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

`<FlatList />` - https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist